# goquery filter doesn't return expected result

Tags: go, goquery

magical internet,

I am trying to filter elements from an html string using "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery". Unfortunately, the filter function does not return the expected result. I would have expected to get back a list of all articles but instead, ... nothing.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

var html = `
<section>
    <article>
        <h1>Article 1</h1>
        <p>Text for article #1</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h1>Article 2</h1>
        <p>Text for article #2</p>
    </article>
</section>
`

func main() {

    qHtml, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(html))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    articles := qHtml.Filter(`article`)

    fmt.Println(articles.Nodes)
    goquery.Render(os.Stdout, articles)
}
```

Comment: Yoiu need to `.Find()` before you `.Filter()`.  You're filtering an empty selection, and it is therefore yielding an empty selection as a result.  See https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery/blob/master/filter_test.go for examples.

Comment: When I update `articles := qHtml.Filter("article")` to `articles := qHtml.Find("section").Filter("article")` still no result, although `qHtml.Find("section")` is a non-empty selection. Could it have something to do with the reason that Filter only searches on the top level? Or should it also search the nested elements?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to filter a selection that is empty.

From what I see you're trying to do in your question, you could simply replace  the `Filter` with `Find`. So in your case it would be:

```
articles := qHtml.Find("article")
```

Once you have a selection containing elements, then you can use `Filter`. So, for example, to get the second article, you could do :

```
articles := qHtml.Find("article").Filter(":nth-child(2)")
```

To read more about `Filter`, check out these resources:

- [goquery documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Filter)
- [jQuery `Filter` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)
- [jQuery `Find` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

`PS`: You can also combine it in single selector to `Find` specific article

```golang
articles := qHtml.Find("article:nth-child(2)")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [`doc`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery)

> [`Filter`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Filter) reduces the set of matched elements to those that match the selector string. It returns a new Selection object for this subset of matching elements.

Since before [`Filter`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Filter) you are not matching anything that's why  you got empty result since [`Filter`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Filter) got no matched elements.

You have to first match elements or get [`Selection`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection) set of nodes before you can apply [`Filter`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Filter)

To solve the issue instead of [`Filter`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Filter) you can use [`Find`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Find) or [`FindMatcher`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.FindMatcher)

```golang
searchStr := `article`

articles := qHtml.Find(searchStr)

articles := qHtml.FindMatcher(goquery.Single(searchStr))
```